# File empty after writing to file obtained with classLoader

Tags: java, file, jackson, writetofile

My simple program is as follows:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory;

public class ProgressionYAMLUtil {
    private final static File PROGRESSFILE_FILE = getProgressionFile();

    public static Boolean write(Progression progression) 
    {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
        try {
            objectMapper.writeValue(PROGRESSFILE_FILE, progression);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static Progression read() 
    {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());

        Progression progression = null;
        try {
            progression = objectMapper.readValue(PROGRESSFILE_FILE, Progression.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        return progression;
    }

    private static File getProgressionFile() {
        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("progress.yaml").getFile());
        return file;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Progression p1 = new Progression("foo");

        p1.newRun(2);
        p1.newRun(9);
        p1.newRun(11);

        System.out.println("WRITE");
        System.out.println(p1);

        Boolean b = write(p1);
        System.out.println("write successfull: " + b);


        System.out.println("READ");
        Progression p2 = read();
        System.out.println(p2);
    }
}
```

For some reason after running this code, my `progress.yaml` file is still empty. The program works fine and the printout is very much expected:

```
WRITE
Progression: foo

0 - 2
1 - 9
2 - 11

write successfull: true

READ
Progression: foo

0 - 2
1 - 9
2 - 11
```

If I run the main method *without* the write-block, the program still reads successfully. How can it read content that isn't there? I looked up the internet whether there are some file cache I should clear to get a better understanding of the issue, but I came out short.

If I change the `writeValue` statement in the `write` method to `objectMapper.writeValue(new File("src/main/resources/progress.yaml"), progression);`, that is obtaining the file without `classLoader`, the program writes to file and the changes are observable.

How come this happens? Thanks for help :)

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right progress.yaml? Maybe you found an old one in another folder? Try to rename it to progress2.yaml in your code, and test again.

Comment: _Resources are **not** files and should be considered **read-only**_.

Comment: @Stefan 100% positive

Comment: @Slaw *Should* they be considered read only, or are they? Also, why can I read the file I seemingly write to? Lastly, how do I go about writing to a file. Is the proposed alternative (the one mentioned at the end of my post) the conventional way to do it? Thanks :)

Comment: It depends. Technically, when the application is in an "exploded directory" and not a JAR file, resources are mapped to files and can be written to. Once packaged in a JAR file the resources are no longer files but are instead entries in a JAR file and cannot be used with the `File` API anymore (for either reading or writing). That's why you should treat them as read-only at all times and only read them via the resource API. Additionally, resources may be _cached_ by the class loader and even if you can write to them that doesn't mean you'll see the new data.

Comment: @Slaw I am building to JAR file so thanks for this info. So if files cannot be written to in JAR, how do I go about storing very simple data? And when you say resource API, which exact API are you talking about here?

Comment: By resource API I mean the `URL` returned by `Class#getResource(String)` or `ClassLoader#getResource(String)` or the `InputStream` returned by `Class#getResourceAsStream(String)`, `ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream(String)` or `Module#getResourceAsStream(String)`. You can obtain an `InputStream` from the `URL` via `URL#openStream()`.

Comment: And you should store application data in an external location. A simple option is the working directory, though that may not be what you expect. Another option is a known location such as an application-specific directory in the user's home directory.

Comment: @Slaw Thanks very much dude! ++kudos